# Duplication Rows by creating same columns in R

Tags: sql, r, xml, database, dataframe

I use below to create a list of AuthorId:

```r
df.Author <- tibble::rowid_to_column(data.frame(df.Author,"AuthorId"))
```

However I want to make the dupilcation as a same id.

[image: current data output]

I want to change the AuthorId in dataframe. Like all Mazumdar's AuthorId is 3 .

What should I do? The reason why I didn't delete the duplication is that there are other attribute in this table are not the same. Just names are duplicating, so I want them to have a same ID.

Comment: Your tags do not align to post. How does XML or SQL fit in here?

Answer (score 0):

We may need `match`

```
nm1 <- with(df.Author, paste(LastName, FirstName))
df.Author$AuthorId <- match(nm1, unique(nm1))
```